# OSX PKG installer - part of background image is hidden

Tags: macos, installation, background-image, pkgbuild, productbuild

I'm trying to build a pkg with a background. I'm working on ElCapt. I'm successful to build pkg with a background image, and here is how it looks like:

[image]

Portion of background image is hidden beneath welcome note.

How can I make this transparent so i could see hidden part of image beneath welcome note part?

Comment: How are you even getting the background image to show at all? In Mojave I am not having any luck with the `background` attribute in `Distribution.xml`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210784/pkg-installer-part-of-background-image-is-hidden, which has sample `xml` provided and some potentially helpful comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `packagesbuild` to generate the pkg installer with which you can customize the background and by default its set transparent. You can also align/scale the image as required.

More details about customization here:
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/Distribution_UI_Customization.html#2

More about Packages tool itself can be found here: 
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/index.html

Comment: This tutorial is helpful, but I do not see anything regarding the transparency being "default" or anything regards to the transparency.